# Django Unicode Decode Error when using field 'date_field' in generic view ArchiveIndexView?

Tags: python, django, unicode

I don't know why this error。 the code ：

```
class ArchiveView(BaseMixin, ArchiveIndexView):

    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'archive_list'
    template_name = 'archive.html'
    date_field = 'pub_time'
```

When trying to access the link of the corresponding view function，This error occurs：
http://7fvg10.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/unicodeerrod.png

'\xd6\xd0\xb9\xfa\xb1\xea\xd7\xbc\xca\xb1\xbc\xe4' mean is 'China standard time'

And I the database code are 'utf8'

I don't speak English is not good. thanks..

Comment: Please post the full traceback. What is `BaseMixin`?

Comment: BaseMixin is my definition of a class , content is                                     ``` class BaseMixin(object):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BaseMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context['recently_article'] = Article.objects.values('title',  'en_name').filter(status=0)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(u'[BaseMixin]加载出错')

        return context  ```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add the code, that makes it easier to read. Please add the full traceback as well, so that we can see where the error is occurring.

Comment: It'd also help if we knew which version of Django and which version of python you were using. (Versions of Django can differ greatly from each other)

Comment: full traceback image :  [link](http://7fvg10.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/unicodeerrod.png)